# Wait for only first response of python microprocessor not all

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Python Flask framework.

I need to use python's multi-processing module. Basically I want to run each job in a separate microprocessor.

Here's my code

```
import multiprocessing

def indexFindSubscriber(self):
    jobs = []

    for idx, val in enumerate(allNetworks):

        print("index is %d and value is %s" % (idx, val['ip']))
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.getEachNode,
                                          args=(val['ip'], self.subscriberId))
        jobs.append(process)

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

     for j in jobs:
         j.join()

        print "List processing complete."
        return "Real Success"
```

This waits for the processes to complete before the return statement. I don't need that. I need the first quickest response and then to kill the remaining processes. How can I do that ?

If I remove .join() method, it just returns and runs the process in background. How can I handle this scenario in Python Flask? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use multiprocessing.Pool and submit your jobs using [imap_unordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered).

Then you can just call `next()` on the resulting iterator to get the first result it returns, followed by terminating the pool.

Alternatively, if you still want to create one process per item (a somewhat risky proposition but you do you) then use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to feed information back from the processes. After starting the children, the parent can just `.get()` on the queue in order to wait for the first success / termination / ..., followed by terminating / killing the children and closing the queue.